# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from tempest==16.0.1.dev178)

Tags: openstack, rally

I just followed the [openstack rally quick start guide](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/rally/quick_start/tutorial/step_10_verifying_cloud_via_tempest_verifier.html) to create a tempest verifier with Rally v0.9.1 in an Openstack Ocata/stable deployment. The command failed:

```
(rally-15.1.2) root@infra1-utility-container-f31faeb0:~/.rally/verification# rally verify create-verifier --type tempest --name tempest-verifier

    2017-05-21 07:53:13.410 11422 INFO rally.api [-] Creating verifier 'tempest-verifier'.
    2017-05-21 07:53:13.528 11422 INFO rally.verification.manager [-] Cloning verifier repo from https://git.openstack.org/openstack/tempest.
    2017-05-21 07:53:37.174 11422 INFO rally.verification.manager [-] Creating virtual environment. It may take a few minutes.
    2017-05-21 07:53:42.323 11422 ERROR rally.verification.utils [-] Failed cmd: '['pip', 'install', '-e', './']'
    2017-05-21 07:53:42.324 11422 ERROR rally.verification.utils [-] Error output: 'Obtaining file:///root/.rally/verification/verifier-091a49ab-1241-40a3-bc9b-531d7f091e37/repo
    Collecting pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from tempest==16.0.1.dev178)
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from tempest==16.0.1.dev178) (from versions: 1.10.0)
    No matching distribution found for pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from tempest==16.0.1.dev178)
    '
    Command failed, please check log for more info
```

As the current version of pbr is 2.0.0, I'm not sure why pbr installation failed.

```
(rally-15.1.2) root@infra1-utility-container-f31faeb0:~/.rally/verification# pip freeze|grep pbr
pbr==2.0.0
```

The question is how to adjust the requirement checking for pbr? or is it possible to choose an older version of tempest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It solved. 
After uploading the two missing python packages: os_testr-0.8.2-py2-none-any.whl and testrepository-0.0.19.tar.gz into local repo, which is a lxc container had been created by openstack-ansible, the Tempest plugin was finally installed.